# PostgreSQL: pass ARRAY[] to pg_query_params

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I need to do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM property_select(ARRAY[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,26,28])
```

using PHP function `pg_query_params($prepared, $params)`.

Prepared query is:

```
SELECT * FROM property_select($1);
```

Params are: `["ARRAY[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,26,28]"]`
How can I pass the params to `pg_query_params()` as array?

It's not possible to use `'{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,26,28}'` postgres arrays (because it may contain strings and strings inside this array may contain , and ").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the detailed requirements for PostgreSQL [Array Input and Output Syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) in the manual.

Basically, you need to enclose array elements with special characters in double quotes `""`. You can double-quote all elements, but you don't have to. And, I quote the manual (see above):

> To put a double quote or backslash in a quoted array element value,
>   use escape string syntax and precede it with a backslash.

There is a [piece of PHP code posted by a user in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php):

```
  //$t is array to be escaped. $u will be string literal.
  $tv=array();
  foreach($t as $key=>$val){
    $tv[$key]="\"" .
      str_replace("\"",'\\"', str_replace('\\','\\\\',$val)) . "\"
";
  }
  $u= implode(",",$tv) ;
  $u="'{" . pg_escape_string($u) . "}'";
```

There is also a [related answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631387/php-array-to-postgres-array):

Also consider the setting of [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS). Backslashes may need to be doubled, but PHP's pg-modules should do that for you automatically.

Comment: [pg_escape_literal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php) may come in handy here.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using the array constructor syntax if you have to do this by hand? Fewer levels of quoting to worry about at least.

Comment: @muistooshort: An array constructor is functionality executed at the server side. Since the above is for a *prepared* statement, passed parameters need to be *values*, hence the array *literal*. Didn't test now, and barely remember this old answer, but I think, that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tricky but efficient and safe way of doing this.

$link: postgresql connection resource

$sql: a query, for example: SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ANY(@ids)

$params: an associative array: $params = array("ids" => array(1,2,3,6));

```
function pg_query_params_assoc($link, $sql, $params)
{   
    $index = 0;
    $assoc = [];
    $hash = [];
    foreach($params as $k => $v)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($k, $hash)) continue;
        if(false === strpos($sql, "@".$k)) continue;
        $hash[$k] = true;

        if(is_array($v))
        {
            $keys = [];
            foreach($v as $item)
            {
                $keys[] = $key = '$'.(++$index);
                $assoc[$key] = $item;
            }           
            $sql = str_replace("@".$k, "array[".implode(',', $keys)."]", $sql);
        }
        else
        {
            $assoc[$key = '$'.(++$index)] = $v;
            $sql = str_replace("@".$k, $key, $sql);         
        }       
    }

    $res = pg_query_params($link, $sql, $assoc);
    return $res;
}
```