# Retrieving php array key and value from postgresql function parameter for database update

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to send an array of key value pairs to a postgresql function as parameter. The structure of the array is following -

```
array(10) { 
  ["OWNER"]=> string(3) "ERP" 
  ["SOURCE"]=> string(7) "Unknown" 
  ["PRIORITY"]=> string(6) "Medium" 
  ["PREFLOC"]=> string(5) "Dhaka" 
  ["PROBABLE"]=> string(2) "50" 
  ["MAXSIZE"]=> string(4) "1000" 
  ["MINSIZE"]=> string(4) "2000" 
  ["INTAREA"]=> string(14) "Dhaka, Gulshan" 
  ["CVALPRF"]=> string(5) "Great" 
  ["OPPAMOUNT"]=> string(3) "200" 
}
```

And the function accepts a string array parameter like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
document.update_doc_attrib_on_opportunity(p_org_id numeric, p_target_doc_code character varying, 
p_target_doc_no numeric, p_doc_attribs character varying[])
```

Now I want to get the array sent to p_doc_attribs inside my function. Like for specific key name I need to insert the desired value in table. 
The following query needs to be updated accordingly -

```
'UPDATE use_doc_attribute
        SET attrib_value = CASE WHEN attrib_code = ''PREFLOC''  THEN ''' || p_preferred_location || '''
                    WHEN attrib_code = ''PRIORITY'' THEN ''' || p_priority || '''
                    WHEN attrib_code = ''PROBABLE'' THEN ''' || p_probability || '''
                    WHEN attrib_code = ''SOURCE''   THEN ''' || p_source || '''
                    WHEN attrib_code = ''MAXSIZE''  THEN ''' || p_max_size || '''
                    WHEN attrib_code = ''MINSIZE''  THEN ''' || p_min_size || '''
                    WHEN attrib_code = ''INTAREA''  THEN ''' || p_interested_areas || '''
                    WHEN attrib_code = ''CVALPRF''  THEN ''' || p_client_value_profile || '''
                    ELSE attrib_value
                   END
        WHERE org_id = ' || p_org_id || '
        AND document_no = ' || p_target_doc_no || '
        AND document_code = ''' || p_target_doc_code || '''';
```

The attrib_code will contain the key and attrib_value for specific case will be the value retrieved from p_doc_attribs array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert at this but you can `json_encode` the array and pass it to your function, for that you will have to make following changes to your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION document.update_doc_attrib_on_opportunity(
    p_org_id numeric, 
    p_target_doc_code character varying, 
    p_target_doc_no numeric, 
    p_doc_attribs JSON)
```

and your query could be like this:

```
'UPDATE use_doc_attribute
    SET attrib_value = CASE WHEN attrib_code = ''PREFLOC''  THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['PREFLOC'] || '''
                WHEN attrib_code = ''PRIORITY'' THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['PRIORITY'] || '''
                WHEN attrib_code = ''PROBABLE'' THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['PROBABLE'] || '''
                WHEN attrib_code = ''SOURCE''   THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['SOURCE'] || '''
                WHEN attrib_code = ''MAXSIZE''  THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['MAXSIZE'] || '''
                WHEN attrib_code = ''MINSIZE''  THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['MINSIZE'] || '''
                WHEN attrib_code = ''INTAREA''  THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['INTAREA']|| '''
                WHEN attrib_code = ''CVALPRF''  THEN ''' || p_doc_attribs['CVALPRF'] || '''
                ELSE attrib_value
               END
    WHERE org_id = ' || p_org_id || '
    AND document_no = ' || p_target_doc_no || '
    AND document_code = ''' || p_target_doc_code || '''';
```

You can check following [link](http://bonesmoses.org/2015/04/10/pg-phriday-functions-and-addressing-json-data/) for more such example.

**EDIT**

I think for this to work you will need PLV8 extension installed you can find more information [here](https://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/postgresql.html)

**EDIT FOR V 9.1.x**

You can create and pass indexed array for example, create array similar to following:

```
[
    "ERP",
    "Unknown",
    "Medium",
    "Dhaka",
    "50",
    "1000",
    "2000",
    "Dhaka, Gulshan",
    "Great",
    "200"
]
```

then use [PHP array to postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631387/php-array-to-postgres-array) function to convert and pass that array to postgresql function and change array values used in query to index based instead of key based as follows:

`p_doc_attribs[3]`

instead of

`p_doc_attribs['PREFLOC']`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out shortly and let you know if it works.

Comment: JSON data type was introduced from PostgreSQL 9.2 but I'm using 9.1.14 which can not be upgraded right now to latest version. So, I guess passing the array as JSON won't work for me at this moment. Can you suggest any other workarounds?

Comment: The edited portion helped and worked perfectly. Thank you