# String of strings and PDO

Tags: php, string, postgresql, pdo

What I'm trying to do is pass an array of content tags into my postgresql database query.

I've got this function:

```
public static function arrayToPdo($array, $pdocon)
{
foreach($array as &$val)
{
$val = $pdocon->quote($val);
}

return implode(",", $array);
}
```

So that converts the array into a string of quoted values.

I've echoed it and I get 'home','test' which are the tags I expected.

So then I want to bind the return value of that function in my PDO. Here's the where part of the query.

```
where @> array[:tags]
```

Now I've substituted the placeholder with the values 'home' and 'test' and it works so the problem lies with how the binding works I think.

When I do the following it works fine:

```
"where @> array[" . arrayToPdo($array, $conn) . "]"
```

So here's the code where I bind the value:

```
$st->bindvalue(":tags", arrayToPdo($array, $conn), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I have another value being bound correctly just before so I feel like it should work.

I've been messing with it for a day and a half and I can't figure it out.

Basically when I enter the quoted values into the query string it works; when I concatenate the function into the query string it works; but when I bind it it doesn't.

There are no errors, I only know it is not working because the query doesn't return any records. I haven't found a way to see what is being inserted into the query string when it is executed so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In `array[:tags]`, `:tags` is a set of values, not a single value. Only single values can be bound.

What you probably want here is to use a syntax for an array that represents it as a single value.

Here: [PHP array to postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631387)
you'll find a function that converts a PHP array into such a syntax.

Then the clause in your query should look like:

```
"... where @> cast(:myarray as text[])"
```

Note that there is no array constructor, it's a cast.

Bind it as

```
$st->bindvalue(":tags", to_pg_array($array), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

making sure that PDO is configured to use real prepared statements:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

(otherwise I suspect that PDO could mess when requoting the parameter. With true prepared statements, parameters are passed by the driver outside of the query and are not quoted).

Comment: Thank you. That was driving me insane. I've only really started in web dev so I've a lot to learn.