# Insert array into database in custom PHP

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

This is my array and I want to insert it in PostgreSQL table in PHP custom. I don't know how to do this.

Array

```
(
    [yearlyno] => Array
        (
            [0] => 999
            [1] => 22
        )

    [mothername] => Array
        (
            [0] => rabia
            [1] => alia
        )

    [husbandname] => Array
        (
            [0] => dan
            [1] => ali
        )

    [mothersage] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 45
        )

)
```

I have searched but could not find any solution.

Please help! I am beginner in PHP.

Comment: what kind of issue are you facing while inserting the record in db?

Comment: not sure about pgsql, but how about having a seperate table for this. This may now seem small set of data but can grow bigger. create a table `people_table` with `array keys` as columns (mothername etc)

Comment: You can use `pg_insert` docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-insert.php). Or convert it in postgresql array ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5632171/2893376))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use while loop and echo $cmdrr [] with DB name in a array

```
while($cmdrr=$dbf->returnDBarray("psql",$_cmdresult)){
  ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $cmdrr['yearlynumber']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $cmdrr['mothername']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $cmdrr['husbandname']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $cmdrr['mothersage']; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [implode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp). This will convert your array in string, or You can convert it in JSON also by [json_encode()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp).

Examples

```
Implode - implode($your_array);
JSON    - json_encode($your_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here. Either use `serialize()` or `json_encode()`
And while retrieving data, you should use `unserialize()` or `json_decode()` respectively.